# Re insert records in Oracle table with Auto generated identifiers using Hibernate

Tags: oracle, hibernate

I have few tables in my database where the primary keys are auto generated using Hibernate seqhilo generator configuration. We need to archive these records and at a later point, should be able to restore them in case of a business scenario. My question is if I restore these tables with simple insert statements will that suffice or should I worry about the sequence generator? I would like to have the same ID and not a new generated one. To be clear these re-inserts will happen via direct SQL and not via Hibernate.